# Can't clone gloox repository

Tags: ubuntu, repository

I want to download [gloox lib](http://code.google.com/p/gloox-for-ios/source/checkout) for iOS. And I can't. I am on Ubuntu. I've downloaded SVN, Git, and other VCS's.

I've tried to enter their SVN checkout command:

```
$ svn checkout http://gloox-for-ios.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gloox-for-ios-read-only
```

But it failed with an error 400 or something like that.

Cloning it as a Git repository fails too:

```
$ git clone http://gloox-for-ios.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gloox-for-ios-read-only
```

> error 'fatal: http://gloox-for-ios.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?'

I can't think of anything else to do!

Comment: The svn checkout works fine for me too. You will not be able to use vanilla Git to clone a Subversion repository, though...

Answer (score 1):

The command line:

```
svn checkout http://gloox-for-ios.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gloox-for-ios-read-only
```

works for me. You are failing to copy and paste or you have a network problem.